# How can I cast on postgres?

Tags: php, postgresql

I want the paid_amount to not be "0", but every-time I run the query I get "No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts." What am I suppose to do? I use PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT
        *
    FROM
        vouchers
    LEFT JOIN voucher_payment ON vouchers.voucher_id = voucher_payment.voucher_id
    LEFT JOIN payment_details ON voucher_payment.payment_id = payment_details.payment_id
    WHERE
        voucher_payment.claim_transfer IS NOT NULL
   AND paid_amount NOT LIKE '0'
```

Comment: The table definition would be nice in order to answer your question, but: it is more than likely, that `paid_amount` is some kind of numerical column, which does not support `LIKE` queries. You can try `paid_amount <> 0` instead. (Or, to include even `NULL`s: `paid_amount IS DISTINCT FROM 0`)

Comment: Alright I did paid_amount != "0"  and it worked, however in the table they still come out but when I ran the query it didn't.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the structure of your table. The `CREATE TABLE` statement would be ideal, and if you're using something like phpPgAdmin or pgAdmin III you should be able to get that easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try varchar<> it worked for me because it might not be numeric 0

Answer (score 0):

You can cast on the fly by issuing a paid_amount::text != '0' for example, however you'll need to be careful that your results are expected. Seeing the table definition will help here.